# For loop returning just one output in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix, sum

I am getting a 49*49 matrix as input from a csv and trying to print the sum as a 49*49 matrix but I am getting just one value as output for sum.

```
w <- read.csv(file="ma.csv", header=F, sep=",");
sum <- 4
for(i in 1:49){
  for(j in 1:49)
  {
    sum = sum + w[i,j];

  }
}
```

Comment: The sum of what are you trying to get?

Comment: @Bruno Perhaps, create a empty matrix of the same size as `w` and assign the values to it for every i,, j. or may be use `outer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be

```
w1 <- matrix(NA, ncol=3, nrow=3)
sum1 <- 4
for(i in 1:3){
 for(j in 1:3){
   w1[i,j] = sum1 + w[i,j];
   }
 }  
w1[] <- cumsum(w1)
```

Or without any loop

```
 w2 <- w 
 w2[] <- cumsum(w+sum1)
 identical(w2, w1)
 #[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
w <- matrix(sample(0:20, 3*3, replace=TRUE), ncol=3)
```